# Argument error when computing quadratic formula

Tags: julia

I am trying to compute the quadratic formula and place the results within an array before printing out the result:

```
function f(a, b, c)
    r1 = (-b+sqrt(complex(b^2-4*a*c)))/2.0*a
    r2 = (-b-sqrt(complex(b^2-4*a*c)))/2.0*a
    x = [r1][r2]
    println(x)
end
```

However I get the following error:

```
f(1, 2, 3)
```

> ArgumentError: invalid index: -1.0 - 1.4142135623730951im of type ComplexF64

Comment: `x = [r1][r2]` this is indexing `[r1]` with `r2` and since `r2` is a complex number, it's illegal to index a `Vector{}` with a complex number.

Comment: what do you want `x` to be?

Comment: I had thought that I could store the variables within a vector, so it would print like: ```[1.453, 2.657]``` as an example. Are there any ways that these values can be stored into a vector?

Comment: It seems to work better when I do this: ```x = [r1, r2]
    return(complex(x))``` thanks for the input @jling

Comment: you can also just return `r1,r2`

Comment: Your quadratic formulas are also wrong. You are multiplying with `a` instead of dividing. Put parentheses around `(2*a)` or write `2a`, without the `*`. Also, it's better to write `2` than `2.0`

Comment: Agreeing with @jiling, don't use a vector here, and don't write `complex(x)`, `x` is already complex. Just write `return (r1, r2)`

Comment: Also note that the standard form of the quadratic formula has some pretty big numerical accuracy issues when one of the roots is close to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code could look like this:

```
function f(a, b, c)
    Δsqrt = √(b^2-4a*c+0im)
    r1 = (-b+Δsqrt)/2a
    r2 = (-b-Δsqrt)/2a
    [r1, r2]  # or use tuple (r1, r2)
end
```

And some exaples:

```
julia> f(1,0,1)
2-element Vector{ComplexF64}:
 0.0 + 1.0im
 0.0 - 1.0im

julia> f(1,0,-1)
2-element Vector{ComplexF64}:
  1.0 + 0.0im
 -1.0 - 0.0im
```